# How can you share quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

So I'm giving The Elder Scrolls Online beta a try and I figured out how to join an ad hoc group. But I can't figure out how to share quests with that group. When I bring up my quests (J key) and then click on one, there is a Share option (F key). However, clicking on it doesn't seem to do anything and the others in my group can't join me in the quest.

So how can I share quests?

Comment: they might need to check their notifications.  Hitting the "N" key will bring up the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen for several reasons:

- They already have the quest
- They already did the quest
- It is a quest line and they haven't advanced far enough yet
- It is a guild quest or a main quest

I have found (experience and logic) that these cause quests to not be 'shareable'. The share button will still be enabled but no notification of any kind is sent to the group or yourself. I have no reference for this however.

Comment: What about quests that don't take place in the proviences of your alliances?